# Origins of the term "High Definition"?

Tags: terminology, technology

I just found a 1996 VHS cassette with 'Super HD' written on it. I was under the impression that 'High Definition' is a relatively new term but it seems pretty old :D.

When did 'High Definition' come into widespread use??

Comment: Chances are the VHS cassette was super *high density*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Analogous to ***HD Radio*** which many assume to mean *High Definition* but which really stands for *Hybrid Digital*. A cynical ploy by marketeers, no doubt (-:

Comment: @JimMack Interestingly enough, _HD Radio_ is a [trademarked](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4809:xtzoy5.2.8) [term](http://hdradio.com/trademark).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've asked two separate questions.

*Origins of the term “High Definition”?*

The term dates back to 1936:

> The term high definition once described a series of television systems originating from August 1936; however, these systems were only high definition when compared to earlier systems that were based on mechanical systems with as few as 30 lines of resolution.
>
> The ongoing competition between companies and nations to create true
> "HDTV" spanned the entire 20th century, as each new system became more
> HD than the last.
>
> In the beginning of the 21st century, this race has
> continued with 4k, 5k and current 8K systems.

*When did 'High Definition' come into widespread use??*

> HDTV technology was introduced in the United States in the late 1980s and made official in 1993 by the Digital HDTV Grand Alliance, a group of television, electronic equipment, communications companies consisting of AT&T Bell Labs, General Instrument, Philips, Sarnoff, Thomson, Zenith and the Massachusetts Institute of Technology.
>
> Field testing of HDTV at 199 sites in the United States was completed August 14, 1994.
>
> The first public HDTV broadcast in the United States occurred on July 23, 1996 when the Raleigh, North Carolina television station WRAL-HD began broadcasting from the existing tower of WRAL-TV southeast of Raleigh, winning a race to be first with the HD Model Station in Washington, D.C., which began broadcasting July 31, 1996 with the callsign WHD-TV, based out of the facilities of NBC owned and operated station WRC-TV.
>
> The American Advanced Television Systems Committee (ATSC) HDTV system had its public launch on October 29, 1998, during the live coverage of astronaut John Glenn's return mission to space on board the Space Shuttle Discovery. The signal was transmitted coast-to-coast, and was seen by the public in science centers, and other public theaters specially equipped to receive and display the broadcast.

However, depending on your definition of "widespread use," HD didn't become widespread in the US until around 2009, when the switch from analog to digital broadcast television occurred, which "transformed the television viewing experience":

> Digital Television is an advanced broadcasting technology that has transformed the television viewing experience. DTV enables broadcasters to offer television with better picture and sound quality, and multiple channels of programming. Since June 13, 2009, full-power television stations nationwide have been required to broadcast exclusively in a digital format.
>
> The switch from analog to digital broadcast television is known as the Digital Television Transition. In 1996, Congress authorized the distribution of an additional broadcast channel to every full-power TV station so that each station could launch a digital broadcast channel while simultaneously continuing analog broadcasting.  Later, Congress set June 12, 2009 as the deadline for full power television stations to stop broadcasting analog signals.

Sources: [Wikipedia article on High-definition television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-definition_television)

[FCC Webpage about Digital Television](https://www.fcc.gov/general/digital-television)

Comment: The USA certainly needed the HDTV in 1996, because, correct me if I'm wrong, the old system was still operating on the 1930s' circa 420 resolution lines.

Comment: It's worth noting that "digital" does not equal "high definition". The ATSC standards allow several decidedly lo-fi versions of TV, and the new sub-channels (e.g. "21.3") are almost always of that variety.

Comment: @JimMack I thought I made that point when I mentioned the analog high-definition television at the outset. While writing my answer, I didn't think that "high definition" was truly widespread in the US by the 90s, so that's why I included the second bit about digital broadcast television; I couldn't think of any other metric to demonstrate when HD became widespread, and I thought that this related milestone was indicative of the HD boom. Do you recommend that I remove that part to prevent confusion? Do you have a superior method to determine when HD "came into widespread use"?

Comment: @kyle Your answer is fine, +1. You noted that high definition could be analog, I emphasized that "digital" could be low definition. Complementary points.

Comment: @WS2  480 lines, roughly ((262 - 22) * 2). Doesn't change your point, though the question of 'need' is of course subjective (-:

Comment: @JimMack The European countries did not introduce colour until the 1960s. When they did they made the German PAL system standard, which used 625 lines. I well remember working  with Americans who were amazed at the better picture standard.

Comment: @WS2  This is fun. Actually, PAL can be (and was) used in 525-line systems in (at least) Brazil. The simple trick of PAL made it clearly superior, regardless of how many lines were scanned. The increased line count of 625 systems is offset by a lower field rate, which causes an annoying -- until you enure to it -- flicker. But now we're chatting. (-:

Answer (score 3):

High definition is from the 30's according to Wikipedia

> - The term high definition once described a series of television systems originating from August 1936; however, these systems were only high definition when compared to earlier systems that were based on mechanical systems with as few as 30 lines of resolution.
> - The ongoing competition between companies and nations to create true "HDTV" spanned the entire 20th century, as each new system became more HD than the last. Ironically, in the beginning of the 21st century, this race has continued with 4k, 5k and current 8K systems.
> - The British high-definition TV service started trials in August 1936 and a regular service on 2 November 1936 using both the (mechanical) Baird 240 line sequential scan (later to be inaccurately rechristened 'progressive') and the (electronic) Marconi-EMI 405 line interlaced systems. The Baird system was discontinued in February 1937.

Answer (score 1):

Actual "High Definition" (compared to the 1936-50s systems regarded as High Definition) i.e. over 1000 lines compared with 405/525/625 line systems were embodied in the early 1980s, by the Japanese Sony/NHK 1125 line 60fps system.

One demonstration of this was by Sony, in late 1982, at the IBC'82 conference in Brighton. It featured almost an entire broadcast chain from cameras through mixer, VT machine and monitors. As far as I know, only the actual transmitter and off-air receiver were missing. Anecdotally, the picture quality was stunning compared to 625 line PAL.

So, from about 1981, "HD" referred to something better than was then broadcast, usually more than 1000 lines resolution.

Considering the slice of radio spectrum you'd need to broadcast an HD channel, it wasn't going to become a practical technology until digital video compression became affordable in the mid-1990s as in Kyle's answer. So from the early 80s it was "the next big thing around the corner".

However it was experimentally used alongside film for some Hollywood productions, shown as part of the demo. This set the scene for [Sony's later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_HDVS) [pro video cameras](http://articles.latimes.com/1990-11-10/entertainment/ca-3854_1_high-definition-technology).